# Docusign Connect Configuration settings not returning PDF

Tags: docusignapi

I have a standard custom connect setup that has been working really well for us.  We now want to store the signed document in our app.  So I go and edit the settings and click on Document PDFs in the include section.  However, there is no change in the XML that is in the callback.  I would have assumed that the base64 encoded document would be there just like when I send it.

Is it somewhere else? Ho do I get a copy of the document once ALL recipients have signed?

Thank You.

Comment: Selecting `Document PDFs` should result in the base64 doc contents being included in the XML payload. Any chance that you have multiple Connect connections configured and that you inadvertently updated the wrong one (i.e., didn't update the one that sends notifications for the `Envelope Complete` event)? Or that you're creating the envelope via API request that specifies Connect notification settings for that particular envelope that are overriding the Connect settings specified at the account level?

Comment: I only have one Connect set up so I am sure I did not update the wrong one. :)  But I do not understand your second point.  I am using a Development Sandbox,  where would I check to see what Connect settings would be overriding my Connect setting for this particular connection?

Comment: When you create an Envelope via API, you can specify Connect settings for that specific envelope by including the `eventNotification` property (object) w/in the `CreateEnvelope` API request.  I'm not 100% sure, but seems like Connect settings specified at the Envelope-level like this would likely override Connect settings specified at the Account-level. If you're not sending the `eventNotification` property as part of the `CreateEnvelope` request though, *and* you've updated the one/only Connect config at the account level, I'm not sure why the doc isn't being included in the XML payload.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you're having this problem. I suggest creating a new Connect subscription/config and sending it to https://www.webhookapp.com/ as a test.

If the payload is as you expect, then update the url to be your webhook listener.

It could also be that you're not parsing the xml fully. The documents are included at an initial object level within the xml.

I do know that if you request the Certificate of Completion without asking for the Document PDFs themselves, it won't work. I haven't seen your problem as described though.

Comment: I simply pulled the envelope ID from the callback XML  and then used the API to pull the documents from there.  That is working just fine.

Comment: Good. In fact, that's the recommended / better way to write your app since it greatly reduces the size of the Connect notification payload